# Exporting an Eclipse build as a .jar file then creating a .exe

Tags: java, eclipse

I've built a program that allows users to create and manage a digital journal and other notes. It works alright and still needs some polishing but that's not the point. It references Java and JavaFx classes through imports. There is only one file, everything is compressed and inside that. It doesn't reference other files, except those created by the program.

I've tried many things, but nothing has seemed to work. I've tried exporting the file as runnable jar file and a normal jar file, changing how the libraries are extracted, changing command line arguments, running it through launch4j (which I still don't grasp a good understanding of, which may be a problem) and nothing has worked. Does anyone know the full process, and can walk me through it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an executable jar file using command prompt

1. We need to create a manifest file i.e " manifest.txt "

   manifest.txt

   Main-Class: classname

Mandatory :  Manifest file should end with the new line character .

Here Main-Class is the entry gate  of the jar file (which we are going to create)  , when anyone click on the executable jar file , JavaHungry main() method will be launched .

2. So we need to create the jar file , so we should always put manifest.txt and  classname.class together .

So in computer directory it will look like

```
C:\java\classname.class
C:\java\manifest.txt
```

So the following  command needs to be executed to create the executable jar of classname file .

```
jar   -cvfm  classname.jar  manifest.txt    *.class
```

Comment: would this be manifest.txt and classname.class (i presume this is the jar???)  in a folder by themselves? and what is inside of manifest.txt?